FATAL: R any reponame username DENIED by fallthru
I have added my .pub key for the repo access .
tried with ssh -T hostname for testing and it's working perfect.
But while trying to clone the repository, I'm getting error like this:
FYI, I'm using Git-Bash in Windows.
FATAL: R any reponame username DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

